# How to specify "onDuplicateXYZ" with a record?

Tags: mysql, jooq

I want to insert a batch of records into a MySQL table, but ignore those who are already there (duplicate primary key).

You can specify an "onDuplicate" strategy when using "dslContext.insert":

```java
create.insertInto(AUTHOR, AUTHOR.ID, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
      .values(3, "Koontz")
      .onDuplicateKeyIgnore()
      .set(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, "Koontz")
      .execute();
```

The question is, how can I do the same with records? Something like this:

```java
var record = dslContext.newRecord(AUTHOR);
record.setField("123");
record.onDuplicateKeyIgnore();
record.store()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such convenience method in jOOQ. The tradeoff here is to assess whether any given convenience (e.g. `INSERT .. IGNORE`) is worth the extra API surface and the dozens of feature interactions this brings. You could try your luck with a [feature request](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose). It won't be implemented soon, but at least, that would allow for collecting upvotes to see community interest in such a feature (e.g. [`UpdatableRecord::merge`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html#merge()) was added due to popular demand).

A simple workaround is to try the `record.insert()` call, and catch and ignore constraint violation exceptions.